# the zip file download from server could not be opened

Tags: java, spring-boot, http

I am using this java(version 11) function to download zip file from server side in Spring Boot (`v2.6.7`):

```
public void downloadPhotoBatchTest() throws IOException {
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(new File("/Users/john/59c49360-3b55-4f97-910e-9f33907f10cb.zip"));
        httpResponse.setContentType("application/zip");
        httpResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + zipFile.getName() + "\"");
        httpResponse.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(zipFile.size()));
        try (OutputStream out = httpResponse.getOutputStream();
             FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("/Users/john/59c49360-3b55-4f97-910e-9f33907f10cb.zip")) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int length;
            while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("write zip to response error", e);
        }
    }
```

but now I found the zip file size will not the same with server side, the downloaded file only have 2KB, and the downloaded file could not be opened. Am I missing something with this code, I read the code but could not found the point where cause this issue. what should I do to fixed this problem? This is the httpResponse define:

```
@Autowired
private HttpServletResponse httpResponse;
```

Comment: Is `httpResponse` some sort of class level variable?  I would have expected it to be passed in to handle threading better.  And try to remove the `out` variable from being closed in the try statement - let your container close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for the content type, your code doesn't need to care if it is a zip file or some other file type. It just needs to transfer the file.

In particular, do not use `ZipFile.size()` for `Content-Length` as `ZipFile.size()` returns the number of files within the zip file while `Content-Length` expects the number of bytes.

You don't specify what `httpResponse` is and where it comes from. And it doesn't look like idiomatic Spring Boot. Better Spring Boot code would be:

```
@RequestMapping("/photoBatch")
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadPhotoBatch() throws IOException {

    File file = new File("/Users/john/59c49360-3b55-4f97-910e-9f33907f10cb.zip");
    InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=" + file.getName())
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/zip")
            .contentLength(file.length())
            .body(resource);
}
```

Comment: `new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));` - this may leak, much better to return `FileSystemResource` as body